# Sequelize wildcare in query param filter

Tags: sequelize.js

I am trying to create a filter

```
router.get('/resources', async (req, res) => {
  const { myAttribute1, myAttribute2 } = req.query;
  let query = {};
  if (myAttribute1) {
    query.myAttribute1 = { $like: myAttribute1 };
  }
  if (myAttribute2) {
    query.myAttribute2 = { $like: myAttribute2 };
  }
  const resources = await findAll(query);
  res.send(resources);
});
```

Then in the model

```
export async function findAll(query) {
  return await Resource.findAll({
    where: {
      ...query
    },
    raw: true
  }).then(result => {
    return result;
  }).catch(err => {
    return err;
  });
}
```

But is not working because the `$like` is wrapped in parenthesis, is there way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed

```
router.get('/resources', async (req, res) => {
  const resources = await findAll(req.query);
  res.send(resources);
});
```

Then in the model

```
const Op = Sequelize.Op;

export async function findAll(query) {
const { myAttribute1, myAttribute2 } = req.query;
  let params = {};
  if (myAttribute1) {
    query.myAttribute1 = { $like: myAttribute1 };
  }
  if (myAttribute2) {
    query.myAttribute2 = { $like: myAttribute2 };
  }
  return await Resource.findAll({
    where: {
      ...params
    },
    raw: true
  }).then(result => {
    return result;
  }).catch(err => {
    return err;
  });
}
```